# object required error Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Sub combine()
    Dim inName, inNum, inCity As String
    Dim IncNum As Integer
    Dim temp As Range
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim cityCells, sNameCells, sNumCells As Range

    cityCells = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells

    For Each Cell In cityCells
        If Cell <> "" And Cell.Row <> 1 Then
            inCity = Cell.Value
            inName = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Cell.Row, 2)
            inNum = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Cell.Row, 3)

            Set temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(what:=inCity)

            If temp Is Nothing Then
            'find the last row of the existing sheet
                lrowEx = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                IncNum = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count

                For counter = 1 To IncNum
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow + 1, counter) = Cells(Cell.Row, counter)
                Next counter

            End If

        End If

       Next

       End Sub
```

I am getting a object required error from the Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow + 1, counter) = Cells(Cell.Row, counter) line, any help?

I am a newbie to vba btw, any thing pointed out about above code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I added another loop you can ignore that. @Elias

```
    Sub combine()
    Dim inName, inNum, inCity As String
    Dim IncNum, inRow, ExcNum As Integer
    Dim temp As Range
    Dim lrowEx As Long
    Dim counter1, counter2 As Integer


    Dim cityCells, sNameCells, sNumCells As Range

    IncNum = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ExcNum = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If IncNum > ExcNum Then
        'find the last column of existing sheet and input sheet
        lcolEx = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        lcolIn = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        For counter1 = lcolEx + 1 To lcolIn
          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, lcolEx + 1) = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells(1, lcolEx + 1)
        Next counter1

    End If

    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell <> "" And cell.Row <> 1 Then
            inCity = cell.Value
            inName = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, 2)
            inNum = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, 3)
            inRow = cell.Row

            Set temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(what:=inCity)

            If temp Is Nothing Then
            'find the last row of the existing sheet
                lrowEx = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

                For counter = 1 To IncNum
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrowEx + 1, counter) = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells(cell.Row, counter)
                Next counter

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Here is my solution. I added another loop you can ignore that. @Elias

Answer (score 1):

I can't make comments, so I'll leave an answer, but are you sure lRow is returning a value? You could be trying to do:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NULL + 1, counter) = Cells(Cell.Row, counter)
```

Also Try

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow + 1, counter).Value = Cells(Cell.Row, counter)
```

ALSO

Your `Cells(Cell.Row,Counter)` is not part of a worksheet object

Comment: "Your Cells(Cell.Row,Counter) is not part of a worksheet object" - I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: Actually I overlooked your For Each statement, my bad!

Comment: Post your solution, I'm curious to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I receive errors before the line that the OP mentions.

You should declare all variables and add `Option Explicit` at the top of the Module to ensure that all variables are declared.

This line

```
Dim cityCells, sNameCells, sNumCells As Range
```

only declares sNumCells as a `Range` the others will be Variants. This means that this line:

```
cityCells = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
```

returns a Variant-array, not a `Range` which causes one of the errors I receive.

Declaring all variables allows the code to run (for me):

```
Dim lRowEx As Long
Dim Cell As Range

Dim cityCells As Range, sNameCells As Range, sNumCells As Range

Set cityCells = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells

For Each Cell In cityCells
```